# Binary Weighted Charge Dac

Tags: adc

I was reading this (https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/1/1080.html)

[image]

I'm wondering, how did they figure out that by switching the MSB capcacitor that it causes a shift of 1/2Vref voltage on the common terminal. Is there some general capacitive divider equation for this?

Comment: The MSB cap has a value of 2^(n-1). The Caps in parallel have values of 2^(n-2), 2^(n-3), ... the value of the MSB cap is equal of the rest of the caps in parallel (plus the dummy cap). Just think about how the binary number 1000 = 8, and 0111 + 0001 also equals 8. From there it comes down to the fact that the capacitors will share charge.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. How do the capacitors share charge though? Is there an equation that defines what the new settled voltage on the common terminal will be after the MSB is switched?

Comment: Q = CV where Q is charge and constant, C is total capacitance and V is voltage